# React: Ant Design - Date Picker

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Hey Guys i have a case that i have 3 types of Date Pickers: Year, Quarter and Month and i need to edit the cells to add some value to it for example for Month is it possible with **monthCellRender** and with this i can edit the cells and add whatever i want on that cell, but can't find anything for Year and Quarter.

This is a link and the example how i did it for month and i want the same for year and quarter:

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4154-forked-8yhlv

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dateRender:)

> Example from documentation:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/2hknl

Comment: This works only for <RangePicker> not for <DatePicker picker="year || month"/>